# How to give root permission to a module?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm working on a module that when I call `echo "hello" > /dev/filename` I get `bash: /dev/filename: permission denied`. For me to get permission I have to call `sudo chmod 666 /dev/filename` and then echo can work. How can I make my module to have root permission so I don't have to call `sudo chmod 666`?

ED: It's a character module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your module permission at initialization, thanks to the `mode` field from the `miscdevice` structure (see [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/miscdevice.h#L76)):

```c
#include <linux/miscdevice.h>

static struct miscdevice my_module_cnf = {
    /*some other fields*/,
    .mode = 0666,
};

static int __init my_module_init(void)
{
    int ret = misc_register(&my_module_cnf);
    if (ret < 0) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "Unable to register my module");
        return ret;
    }

    return 0;
}

static void __exit my_module_exit(void)
{
    misc_deregister(&my_module_cnf);
}

module_init(my_module_init);
module_exit(my_module_exit);
```

Comment: ...and if it's **not** a misc device?

Comment: I tried this but I get  `insmod: ERROR: could not insert module  ./filename.ko: Cannot allocate memory`

Comment: @0andriy High is the chance that it actually is for this kind of question.

Comment: @Renato Can you see it in `/dev/` already? Do you see anything related when entering `dmesg | grep filename` that would help debugging?

Answer (score 0):

> my module to have root permission

A kernel module runs at the kernel level - it has all possible permissions to do anything with anything.

1. You can either change the permission of the character device, which you can do for example with `chmod`.
2. Or alternatively elevate the permission of the process that is is writing to the character device file, which you can do by for example running your shell with root permisions `sudo sh -c 'echo hello > /dev/filename'` or pipeing the data to `sudo tee`.

Comment: The problem with those solutions is that both require a sudoer account, which may not be expected here. If you're the module owner and you want to allow non-root users to use it, you can do it programmatically at initialization (see my answer).

Comment: Why do you think it's a *character* device?

Comment: I _guessed_ it's a character device, because it's most common to start kernel programming with a character device. I do not think it matters for the purpose of my answer. Ask OP for additional information if you're interested in.

Answer (score -1):

Assume the `file` you want to write to is a character device. You can do it programmatically by overwriting `dev_uevent` of the class created for the device like below.

```
static struct class *cl;

int my_uevent(struct device *dev, struct kobj_uevent_env *env)
{
    add_uevent_var(env, "DEVMODE=%#o", 0666);
    return 0;
}

.....

int my_init(void)
{
    int ret;
    struct device *dev_ret = NULL;

    if((ret = alloc_chrdev_region(&dev, FIRST_MINOR, MINOR_CNT, "char_dev")) < 0)
    {
        return ret;
    }
    printk("Major Nr: %d\n", MAJOR(dev));

    cdev_init(&c_dev, &fops);

    if((ret = cdev_add(&c_dev, dev, MINOR_CNT)) < 0)
    {
        unregister_chrdev_region(dev, MINOR_CNT);
        return ret;
    }

    if(IS_ERR(cl = class_create(THIS_MODULE, "chardrv")))
    {
        cdev_del(&c_dev);
        unregister_chrdev_region(dev, MINOR_CNT);
        return PTR_ERR(cl);
    }

    cl->dev_uevent = my_uevent; // <-- overwrite dev_uevent here

    if(IS_ERR(dev_ret = device_create(cl, NULL, dev, NULL, "mychar%d", 0)))
    {
        class_destroy(cl);
        cdev_del(&c_dev);
        unregister_chrdev_region(dev, MINOR_CNT);
        return PTR_ERR(dev_ret);
    }
    return 0;
}
```